# Solve System of Differential equations w/o using matrices.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a pretty simple question here it looks like but I just can't seem to do it. I'd like to be able to do it the easiest way possible.

> Solve  $\dot{x}=y$ and $\dot{y}=x$ for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

I need solve these two equations so I can draw a phase plane portrait and sketch trajectories. I'll be able to do that fine but not sure why I'm struggling with this problem.

I can use the chain rule to solve the system together but I'd like to get $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ alone. What is the best way to do this problem, is there any little tricks I can use. Thanks I'm not expecting you to do the problem, just a little nudge in the right way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to solve

$$\begin{cases}x' = y \quad (1)\\y' = x\quad (2)\end{cases}$$

where both $x,y$ are functions of $t$.

Differentiate both sides of $(1)$, obtaining:

$x'' = y'$

Then, use $(2)$ to find $x'' = x$ or $x'' - x = 0$

We search the roots of the associated polynomial: $r^2 -1 = 0 \iff r = -1$ or $r = 1$

Hence, $x = c_1e^{-t} + c_2e^t$

By plugging this in $(1)$, we find $y = -c_1e^{-t} + x_2e^t$

Hence, the solution of your system is:

$$\begin{cases}x = c_1e^{-t} + c_2e^t\\y = -c_1e^{-t} + c_2e^t\end{cases}$$

Comment: 1) One could say that in general it is equivalent to solve a first order differential system with constant coefficients with $n$ equations and a unique $n$th order linear differential equation with constant coefficients. 2) It should be said something on the initial conditions.

Comment: no initial conditions were given

Comment: I have seen. But, one should say to the OP that initial conditions are essential and must accompany any differential system.

Comment: Strictly mathematically speaking, this is a correct solution and no initial conditions are needed. For every two constants $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, this is a solution. But this looks like a phyiscs problem in disguise so probably you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can differentiate both equations wrt. time and plug one into the other and vice-versa. I mean:
$$\dot{x}=y\tag{1}$$
$$\dot{y}=x\tag{2}$$

Differentiating $(1)$ and introducing $(2)$ you have:
$$\ddot{x}=\dot{y}=x$$
doing an analogous procedure with $(2)$
$$\ddot{y}=y$$

Answer (score 1):

You get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(y^2-x^2)=2(y\dot y-x\dot x)=0
$$
so that all solutions lie on the hyperbolic curves $y^2-x^2=C$.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it now. So if I had this problem

$$\dot{x}=y \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ $$ \dot{y}=-2x \,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$

Differentiate $(1)$

$$\ddot{x}= \dot{y}= -2x \implies \ddot{x}-2x=0$$

This equation has characteristic polynomial $P(\lambda)$

$$P(\lambda) = \lambda^2-2=0$$

with roots

$$\lambda_{\pm}= \pm\sqrt{2}$$

The solution of a 2nd order DE with two distinct real roots is of the form

$$\begin{align}
x(t)& =Ae^{\lambda_1 t}+Be^{\lambda_2 t} \\
    & = Ae^{\sqrt{2}t} +Be^{-\sqrt{2}t}
\end{align}$$

Using our relationship in equation $(1)$

$$y(t) =  \sqrt{2}Ae^{\sqrt{2}t} -\sqrt{2}Be^{\sqrt{2}t}$$

Does this seem right to you guys? Thanks very much for all your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct! You can accept the answer that helped you the most so other users know that your question has been solved.

Comment: I did it while you were typing, thanks very much for the help. Much appreciated.